# Всем ПРИВЕТ!!!!! У меня проблема

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня когда я пишу метод "OnTriggerEnter" у меня вот эта ошибка. Я новичок [image: вот эта]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Может быть всё же код покажешь?

Comment: На скрине кстати нет метода OnTrigger**Enter**

Comment: "У меня в коде ошибка, но код я не покажу, вангуйте, друзья"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Буду ванговать

Первая ошибка говорит что метод не абстрактный и значит нужно описывать тело метода (основы программирования здравствуйте)

Вторая ошибка вероятно говорит о том, что где-то есть уже такой файл с такими же методами. Т.е. ты накопировал один и тот же файл по папкам и он теперь конфликтует. Либо уже такой метод в этом файле есть, с той же сигнатурой, а ты пытаешься ещё один такой же писать.

Comment: Спасибо очень помогли!!!!